# Programatically scroll to the top of the screen of Windows 7 command prompt

Tags: command-line

Is there a command I can run to scroll to the top left of a command prompt window? Set the y and x scrollbars to 0?

When I programatically increase the console window like this:

```
mode con:cols=9999 rows=9999
```

command prompt automatically positions itself right at the bottom, which makes sense, but I want to position at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood your question correctly:

1. You can use `more` as a pipe, e.g. `dir | more`
2. You can send the output to a text file e.g. `dir > c:\myfile.txt`
3. Try using [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) terminal/console and bash, it has powerful commands and packages.